# Column Tree Model doesn't expand node after EXPAND_NO_CHILDREN event

Tags: events, treeview, abap

I am displaying a list of items using a SAP ABAP column tree model, basically a tree of folder and files, with columns.

I want to load the sub-nodes of folders dynamically, so I'm using the EXPAND_NO_CHILDREN event which is firing correctly.

Unfortunately, after I add the new nodes and items to the tree, the folder is automatically collapsing again, requiring a second click to view the sub-nodes.
Do I need to call a method when handling the event so that the folder stays open, or am I doing something else wrong?

```
* Set up event handling.
  LS_EVENT-EVENTID  = CL_ITEM_TREE_CONTROL=>EVENTID_EXPAND_NO_CHILDREN.
  LS_EVENT-APPL_EVENT = GC_X.
  APPEND LS_EVENT TO LT_EVENTS.
  CALL METHOD GO_MODEL->SET_REGISTERED_EVENTS
    EXPORTING
      EVENTS                    = LT_EVENTS
    EXCEPTIONS
      ILLEGAL_EVENT_COMBINATION = 1
      UNKNOWN_EVENT             = 2.
  SET HANDLER GO_APPLICATION->HANDLE_EXPAND_NO_CHILDREN
    FOR GO_MODEL.

...


* Add new data to tree.
  CALL METHOD GO_MODEL->ADD_NODES
    EXPORTING
      NODE_TABLE = PTI_NODES[]
    EXCEPTIONS
      ERROR_IN_NODE_TABLE = 1.

  CALL METHOD GO_MODEL->ADD_ITEMS
    EXPORTING
      ITEM_TABLE = PTI_ITEMS[]
    EXCEPTIONS
      NODE_NOT_FOUND = 1
      ERROR_IN_ITEM_TABLE = 2.
```

Comment: It might be some obscure arrangement of flags - could you try to post a minimal working example?

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I've played with SAP, but I always found the SAP Library to be particularly helpful when I got stuck...

I managed to come up with this one for you:
http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/47/aa7a18c80a11d3a6f90000e83dd863/frameset.htm, specifically:

> *When you add new nodes to the tree model, set the flag ITEMSINCOM to 'X'.
>
>   This informs the tree model that you want to load the items for that node on demand.*

Hope it helps?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine,

I would use the method `ADD_NODES_AND_ITEMS` myself if I were to add nodes and items ;)

Beyond that, try to call `EXPAND_NODE` after you added the items/nodes and see if that helps.